# ¿Como arreglo el problema de executeUpdate de JAVA SQL?

Tags: java, sql

Tengo problemas al almacenar datos en una base de datos.
Código del error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (Area,Article,Amount,Date) VALUES ('Logistica','tornillo',5,'')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
at net.luisalvacelis.sv.utils.administrator.Order.setOrderSQL(Order.java:225)
at
```

Mi código:

```
public void setOrderSQL(String area,String articulo,int cant,String data){
    String url="INSERT INTO order (Area,Article,Amount,Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        SQL sql=new SQL();
        Connection cn=sql.dataBase();
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement(url);
        ps.setString(1, area);
        ps.setString(2, articulo);
        ps.setInt(3, cant);
        ps.setString(4, data);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0){
            JOptionPaneOwner.showMessageDialog("Éxito", "Pedido realizado con éxito.", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/net/luisalvacelis/sv/image/exito32x32.png")));
            updateInformation("");
        }else{
            JOptionPaneOwner.showMessageDialog("Error", "Error: Hubo un error al hacer el pedido, consulte con el creador del programa.", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/net/luisalvacelis/sv/image/error32x32.png")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ya he probado con varias alternativas, pero sigue mandándome, también utilicé ese código en otra clase y si me funciona, por ello pido su ayuda, espero respuestas, gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER es una [palabra reservada](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) de la BD. Tu tabla no puede llamarse order porque estos problemas comienzan a aparecer.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Usas ese nombre entre comillas por siempre para decir que es un literal y no la palabra reservada.
- Cambias el nombre de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

El nombre de la tabla es una "palabra reservada", por esa razón el error:

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'order (Area,Article,Amount,Date) VALUES
>   ('Logistica','tornillo',5,'')' at line 1

Usa el `backtick` ( ` ) como contenedor del nombre.

```
"INSERT INTO `order` (Area,Article,Amount,Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
```

**No es buena practica usar palabras reservadas como nombres de tablas o campos.**

Aquí una [lista de palabras reservadas usadas en MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) que no deberías usar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que el nombre de tu tabla tiene el nombre de una palabra reservada de tu DB, mi consejo como tal es que realices el cambio del nombre de la tabla para que no presentes el inconveniente.

Por lo general el gestor de base de datos que uses te va a indicar si la palabra es reservada poniéndola del mismo color que las palabras de ejecución ("Select", "where", "Alter", etc.)

Saludos